# Inconsistent mouse behavior in Lion

Tags: usb, mouse, macos

Two different mice?mouses? work for a while and then the light connection gets intermittent and eventually is lost. The pointer is then inactivated - but I can use the scroll wheel on the mouse and activate the right click button.

Comment: Hi Jane, welcome.  Please can I ask you to provide more details, what OS and hardware you are using?  This will help us help you faster :)  Thanks.

Comment: Do mean two mice connected at the same time?  Or one connected at a time, exchanging them as a test?

Comment: *a previous post* — which post? (And if it's the same, then that smells like a duplicate?)

Answer (score 1):

Are they plugged into the same 'upstream' USB device, such as two ports on the same keyboard?  Ideally, you'd have them plugged into individual USB ports on the Mac itself.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear.

Comment: MacAir, OS Lion, one mouse at a time, same problem. Mouse 1 worked for a couple of weeks post upgrade, then light started to flicker and eventually went out. No light, no pointer movement. Scroll and right click work. Mouse 2 stopped working after one day (same outcome). Devices don't work on Windows now, but Control Panel say they are working correctly.

Comment: Realized i forget the troubleshooting step you ALWAYS try first... Shut down MacAir and retried mouse. It worked - for 53 minutes!  Now, lights up for several seconds and then shuts off. [Shut down the Windows machine and other mouse works again on that.]